# how to avoid Cross-Origin Request Blocking in NW.js

Tags: javascript, nwjs, apple-musickit

I am trying to create an NW.js app that uses Apple's MusicKitjs API.

MusicKit pops up an Auth window when you go to login via the standard "login to Apple Music" button. That looks like this in my app:

[image: musickitjs auth]

Eventually it makes a request to apple.com that fails, with two errors: "Unexpected end of JSON input" and a "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response":

[image: Apple music CORB error]

NWjs has a page specifically addressing CORB issues  [here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/). I believe I have followed all of them. Here is a snippet of my manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "NW.js React App",
  "name": "Create NW.js React App Sample",
  "nodejs":true,
  "node-remote":".apple.com",
  "chromium-args" : "--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating",
}
```

As you can see, I also tried telling Chromium to disable CORB. But none of this is working. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `node-remote` to a valid pattern like:

```
"node-remote":"https://*.apple.com/*"
```